# Average speed and top speed of array "CoreLocation"

Tags: arrays, swift, average

I`m trying to display the users average speed,
and I also want to display the highest value of the array.

I searched the forums and found many ways to accomplish this, but nothing works.

What I have tried is in the `// top speed` and `// average speed`

Here is my code:

```
// Location
let manager = CLLocationManager()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.015, 0.015)
    let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    // Altitude
    let altitude = location.altitude
    let altitudeNoDecimals = Int(altitude)

    altitudeLabel.text = "\(altitudeNoDecimals)"

    // m/s to km/h
    let kmt = location.speed * (18/5)
    let kmtLabel = Int(kmt)
    statusLabel.text = "\(kmtLabel)"

    // Top Speed
    // let maxSpeed: Int = (kmtLabel as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "@maxSpeed.self") as! Int
    // topSpeedLabel.text = "\(maxSpeed)"

    let max = location.toIntMax()
    topSpeedLabel.text = "\(max)"

    // Average speed
    var avg: Double = (list as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("@avg.self") as Double
    averageSpeed.text = "\(avg)"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to save all speed updates into an array yourself, which should be defined as a class instance property and you can define both average speed and top speed as computed properties so you don't need to update them manually every time you receive location updates.

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
var speeds = [CLLocationSpeed]()
var avgSpeed: CLLocationSpeed {
    return speeds.reduce(0,+)/Double(speeds.count) //the reduce returns the sum of the array, then dividing it by the count gives its average
}
var topSpeed: CLLocationSpeed {
    return speeds.max() ?? 0 //return 0 if the array is empty
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    ...

    speeds.append(contentsOf: locations.map{$0.speed}) //append all new speed updates to the array

    // m/s to km/h
    let kmt = location.speed * (18/5)
    let kmtLabel = Int(kmt)
    statusLabel.text = "\(kmtLabel)"

    // Top Speed
    topSpeedLabel.text = "\(topSpeed)"

    // Average speed
    averageSpeed.text = "\(avgSpeed)"
}
```

Bear in mind that I didn't change the unit of either `avgSpeed` or `topSpeed` to km/h, if you need that, you can either do it before writing them to labels or rather before appending them to the array.

Comment: Thank you for making the effort to implement your answer in my code and the explaining comments. It worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: During calculation of average speed, this solution assumes that distances between CLLocation samples are the same. And this assumption is wrong. You should take into account distances as well.